# Logstash grok match pattern for message field

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

my log data is like,

[image: log messages in the file].

There are total 4 lines are there(Starting from Date with Time).

**My grok pattern is:**

```
grok { 
match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} \[%{NUMBER:thread}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{JAVACLASS:class} - %{GREEDYDATA:msg} " } }
```

**Problem is:**

I am getting only some data of **msg**(GREEDYDATA) filed.

**EX:**

Below **data is missing** when the 4th line parsing

[image: missed data]

log is :

```
2015-01-31 15:58:57,400 [9] ERROR NCR.AKPOS.Enterprise_Comm.EventSender - EventSender.SendInvoice() Generate Message Error: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
   at System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute..ctor(XName name, Object value)
   at NCR.AKPOS.Enterprise_Comm.MessageHandlerObjecttoXMLHelper.CreateXMLFromInvoice(Invoice invoice, Customer_ID customer_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Log stash typically parses each line at a time. 
For java exceptions you need to look at the [multiline plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html). 
See an example here: https://gist.github.com/smougenot/3182192

Your grok format seems ok, but without an example cannot be tested. 
You can use the grok debugger app to test out your patterns.
https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I already check with the GrokDebugger @Yogesh_D. I find the below pages for my problem but am unable to solve my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172879/how-to-process-logstash-multiline-filters-message-field

Comment: Well you need to edit your question to have the log you are trying to parse, so that we can have  a go at it

Comment: Please see the edited post add the log at end of the post

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the trailing white spaces from `%{GREEDYDATA:msg} " }` to 
`%{GREEDYDATA:msg}"}`

**So, total filter configuration is:**

```
filter {
multiline{
        pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"
        what => "previous"
        negate=> true
    }
# Delete trailing whitespaces
  mutate {
    strip => "message"
  }
# Delete \n from messages
mutate {
    gsub => ['message', "\n", " "]
}

# Delete \r from messages
mutate {
    gsub => ['message', "\r", " "]
}
grok { 
  match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} \[%{NUMBER:thread}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{JAVACLASS:class} - %{GREEDYDATA:msg}" } 
}
if "Exception" in [msg] {
 mutate {
  add_field => { "msg_error" => "%{msg}" }
}
}
}
```